# Holomorphic Function $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2-3i)\cdot \dfrac{1}{n! z^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2-3i)\cdot \dfrac{1}{n! z^n}$

Prove that this function is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and calculate $$\int_{|z|=2} g(z)\,\mathrm{d}z$$

Edit:

What  I have done:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
g(z) & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2-3i)\cdot \dfrac{1}{n! z^n}\\
     & = (2-3i)\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n! z^n}\\
     & = (2-3i)\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{-n}}{n!}\\
     & = (2-3i)\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{-n}}{n!} - \dfrac{z^{-0}}{0!}\\
     & = (2-3i)\cdot  (e^{z^{-1}} -1)\\
     & = (2-3i)  e^{z^{-1}}  -(2-3i) \\
     & = 2e^{z^{-1}} - 3ie^{z^{-1}} +3i - 2
\end{split}
\end{align}

let $z^{-1}=z^*$ for a $z^* = x+ iy$

Then let's see $2e^{z^{*}} - 3ie^{z^{*}} +3i - 2$ is holomorphic

Proof:

$ 2e^{z^{*}} - 3ie^{z^{*}} +3i - 2$

$ = 2e^{x + iy} - 3ie^{x + iy} +3i - 2 $

$ = 2e^{x} e^{iy} - 3ie^{x}e^{iy} +3i - 2 $

$ = 2e^{x} [ \cos(y) + i \sin(y) ] - 3 ie^{x} [ \cos(y) + i \sin(y) ] +3i - 2 $

$ = 2e^{x}\cos(y) + 2 i e^{x} \sin(y) - 3 ie^{x} \cos(y) - 3 i^2 e^{x} \sin(y)+3i-2 $

$ = 2e^{x}\cos(y) + 2 i e^{x} \sin(y) - 3 ie^{x} \cos(y) + 3 e^{x} \sin(y) +3i - 2 $

$ = 2e^{x}\cos(y) + 3e^{x} \sin(y) - 2 + 2 i e^{x} \sin(y) - 3 i e^{x} \cos(y) +3i $

$ = 2e^{x}\cos(y) + 3e^{x} \sin(y) - 2 + i[2 e^{x} \sin(y) - 3 e^{x} \cos(y) +3] $

Now let $u(x,y) = 2e^{x}\cos(y) + 3e^{x} \sin(y) - 2$

And let $v(x,y) = 2 e^{x} \sin(y) - 3 e^{x} \cos(y) +3$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you recognize this series?

Comment: I tried to expand the series but I didn't see anything.

Comment: No, I mean this is already a series you would be responsible for knowing in a complex analysis class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. would it be if the series is equal to $e^{(z^{-1})}$ ?

Comment: Yes indeed! (up to the factor $2-3i$) (oh, and other than the constant term, since the sum "should" start at $n=0$ but starts at $n=1$)

Comment: The integral is $2\pi i \cdot \text{Res}_{z=0}g(z).$

Comment: What do you need that factor $2-3i$ for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was discussed in the comments that $g(z)=(2-3i)(e^{1/z}-1)$ is holomorphic in the complex plane excluding the origin.  The function $e^{1/z}$ is a composition of holomorphic functions, thus holomorphic.

The residue is $2-3i$ so the integral evaluates to $2 \pi i \cdot(2-3i)$.